# Travis build gcc fails include plugin header

Tags: gcc, travis-ci

I am trying to build a project with Travis. The Makefile has the following include:

```
-I$(shell $(TARGET_CC) -print-file-name=plugin)/include
```

Which was supposed to give the `plugin` directory for `gcc`.

```
${CC} -print-file-name=plugin
plugin
${CC} -print-file-name=plugin/include/gcc-plugin.h
plugin/include/gcc-plugin.h
${CC} -print-file-name=gcc-plugin.h
gcc-plugin.h
```

Build fails with error:

```
fatal error: gcc-plugin.h: No such file or directory
```

This header is supposed to be located in the `gcc` `plugin` library. What could go wrong with it?

Project is open sourced at https://github.com/aoboturov/lua-hdf5

Comment: Is your second code block output from a test on travis or your local machine?

Comment: @renemilk everything is from travis: [https://travis-ci.org/aoboturov/lua-hdf5/jobs/134399346](https://travis-ci.org/aoboturov/lua-hdf5/jobs/134399346)